# How to build Android app in release mode? GoogleFit: RESULT_CANCELED

Tags: java, android, google-fit-sdk, google-fit-api

Can anyone tell me how to build my app in release mode? I'm having issues getting to the permissions screen on my android (java) application, I keep getting `GoogleFit: RESULT_CANCELED` error and then activity closes.

Another user suggested building in release mode, my SDK is generated for release and I have updated my gradle files but nothing is working.

I have asked for help a few times since yesterday with no luck so if anyone can help that would be appreciated!

[Link to my other question with problem in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67895323/result-canceled-error-returned-onactivityresult-method)

Comment: Are you using Android Studio or what IDE?

Comment: @Ctrl_see yes I am using Android Studio sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using Android studio. To build the app in release mode. You will need to find a window called `Build Variants` which should be at the lower left screen of you workspace. And you will see the modules you created for your APP. And just change `Build Variants` from `debug` to `release`.

Here is the official document link for your reference [Build and Run your App.](https://developer.android.com/studio/run)

Comment: This option is greyed out for me on my Android Studio..

Comment: Okay actually it came up since going to app level gradle, managed to find the release mode! Thanks so much, now got a whole other error to deal with though sadly haha

Answer (score 1):

If you sre using Android Studio then you can go to build > Build Signed Bundle/APK....proceed and at the end Mark "release".

For more details you can search "android studio Generation Signet APK".
But I believe your problems lie deeper than that, I dont think it has anything to do with how you build your APK.

Comment: I have already done that, hence my confusion lol. Will try above answer and see. I cant get my API to work at all and I've tried everything except for the release mode build.

Comment: The above answer is my answer in other words. But appart from that, I believe that your problems don't have anything to do with build variants. You should probably research some more about the particular error

Comment: Thanks, yeah I figured it out a bit.. but then messed it up so had to start again.. the joys. Thanks for your help.